# Collection through other models Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm unsure how to word this as I'm not sure what the right term for this is, but..

I have a user model.  This model can create Trains.  such that user.trains has all their trains.  This model can also create Buses, such that user.buses has all their buses.  Trains and Buses can both contain Cargo.  user.trains.cargo and user.buses.cargo.

How would i set this up so that I can just ask for User.cargo and get all the cargo from both the trains and the buses, without having to call the .cargo list for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single table inheritance answer might be great for you, especially if Trains and Buses have mostly the same data about them. However, if those models are very different than one another you might want a different solution.

What if you defined a simple method on your user class?

```
class User
  has_many :trains
  has_many :buses

  def cargo
    trains.map(&:cargo) + buses.map(&:cargo)
  end
end
```

This answer assumes that **each** `Bus` and `Train` has a cargo, which is different than your example showing `User.trains.cargo`.

Comment: Many great answers here, but this is the closest to what I implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can [use the concept of Single Table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) in rails.

As you have both `Trains` and `Buses`, both of which can be said to be types of a `Vehicle`, you can have a base model `Vehicle`, and let both `Train` and `Bus` inherit from the `Vehicle` as follow:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Train < Vehicle; end
class Bus < Vehicle; end
```

And then, your `User` class can have a `one-to-many` association to `Cargo` through `Vehicle`.

Like this, if you call `user.cargoes` (`user` being an instance of a `User`), the result should be all the cargoes of the specified user.

Hope this throws some light on the issue for you...

Comment: This didnt work for all situations I had the issue, but great answer

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) seems promising.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buses
  has_many :trains

  scope :cargoes, ->{buses.select(:cargo).union_all(trains.select(:cargo))}
end
```