# How to build a model form that has has_many relations on its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a `Phrase` class that `has_many` `Phrase` as `Translation`.

#### app/models/phrase.rb

```
class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translatabilities
  has_many :translations, through: :translatabilities
  has_many :inverse_translatabilities, class_name: "Translatability", foreign_key: "translation_id"
  has_many :inverse_translations, through: :inverse_translatabilities, source: :phrase
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translatabilities
end
```

#### app/models/phrases_controller.rb

```
class PhrasesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @phrases = Phrase.all.page params[:page]
    @translations = @phrases.count.times.map do |i|
      translation = Phrase.new
      translation.translatabilities.build
      translation
    end
  end
end
```

And I want to add "translatability" forms for each "phrase".

#### app/views/phrases/index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <% @phrases.each do |phrase| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= phrase.text %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= form_for @translations do |f| %>
              <%= f.text_field :text %>
              <%= f.submit 'translate' %>
              <%= f.fields_for :translatabilities do |t_form| %>
                  <%= t_form.hidden_field :id %>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This code has infinite loop bug.

```
undefined method `phrase_phrase_phrase_phrase_phrase_phrase_...
```

How can I create forms for translation of original phrases?

#### app/models/translatability.rb

```
class Translatability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phrase
  belongs_to :translation, :class_name => 'Phrase'
end
```

Comment: [Check this questionhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510519/collection-through-other-models-rails-4/33511017#33511017)

Comment: I know STI. Should I use STI in this case?

Comment: yes. so, you can have both an original phrase, as well as a translated phrase. By so, you can have a single table inheritance to phrase.

Comment: No, a phrase instance is treated also a translation of other phrases, like a `Friend` is a `User` same time, but you can't make a `Friend` class with STI. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If you would want to make a `Friend` using STI all you would need to do is inherit from `User` like `class Friend < User; end`. You could do the same with `Translation` and `Phrase`

Comment: wait, you are using `translations`..., and especially, `translatabilities`. Where is your `translatability` model? could you show that?

Comment: `translatabilities` is a intermediate table for many to many relationships. (I doubt that I choose a good word, though.) I added the model in my question

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be complicating things a bit with this method.  If I understand correctly, you have `Phrase`s that can be translated into multiple languages. It seems to me that what you really want to have is a `Phrase` model that defines the language and has a reference to allow other translations to be related.

`Phrase` would look something like this:

```
create_table :phrases do |t|
  t.text :body
  t.string :locale
  t.integer :translation_ref_id
end
```

In the `Phrase` model you can define `translations` methods:

```
def translations
  self.class
    .where(translation_ref_id: translation_ref_id)
    .where.not(id: id)
end
```

In your form, you would have multiple `Phrases` instead of a single `Phrase` with nested attributes. And in the controller, you would set the `translation_ref_id` for each of the `Phrase`s (you could use any unique identifier, incrementing integer ids are good; you don't need a separate model to keep track of ids).

Comment: As far as I know if `Phrase` model have a reference id for `Translation` model, that means `Translation` has_many `phrases`, isn't it?

Comment: My answer is an example of how to relate phrases without using STI. Asking `Phrase` for its translations, returns other `Phrase` objects.